# Reading and writing into etree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xml.etree

I am new to etree. I wanted to read etree and put that particular information in another file format like html, xml, etc. I checked and now I can do that but now what about other way around? Like, If I want to read any other file format and generate or write into etree. Please give me some suggestions or with example to proceed with that.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to write an xml file test.xml like the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
<document category = "location">
    <name>Timbuktu</name>
    <name>Eldorado</name>
</document>
```

The corresponding code would be:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.Element("document", {"category" : "locations"})
for location in ["Timbuktu", "Eldorado"]:
    name = etree.SubElement(root, "name")
    name.text = location
tree = etree.ElementTree(element=root, file=None, parser=None)
tree.write('test.xml', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)
```

If you want to add further sub-elements under name then you have to nest another for loop and create subelements under the name tag object.